# How to dynamically format string representation of float number in python?

Tags: python, string, formatting

Hi I would like to dynamically adjust the displayed decimal places of a string representation of a floating point number, but i couldn't find any information on how to do it.

E.g:

`precision = 8`

`n = 7.12345678911`

`str_n = '{0:.{precision}}'.format(n)`

`print(str_n)` should display -> `7.12345678`

But instead i'm getting a "KeyError". What am i missing?

Comment: `print('{0:.{1}}'.format(n, precision)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify where `precision` in your format string comes from:

```
precision = 8
n = 7.12345678911
print('{0:.{precision}}'.format(n, precision=precision))
```

The first time, you specified which argument you'd like to be the number using an index (`{0}`), so the formatting function knows where to get the argument from, but when you specify a placeholder by some key, you have to explicitly specify that key.

It's a little unusual to mix these two systems, i'd recommend staying with one:

```
print('{number:.{precision}}'.format(number=n, precision=precision))  # most readable
print('{0:.{1}}'.format(n, precision))
print('{:.{}}'.format(n, precision))  # automatic indexing, least obvious
```

It is notable that these precision values will include the numbers before the point, so

```
>>> f"{123.45:.3}"
'1.23e+02'
```

will give drop drop the decimals and only give the first three digits of the number.
Instead, the `f` can be supplied to the type of the format [(See the documentation)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) to get fixed-point formatting with `precision` decimal digits.

```
print('{number:.{precision}f}'.format(number=n, precision=precision))  # most readable
print('{0:.{1}f}'.format(n, precision))
print('{:.{}f}'.format(n, precision))  # automatic indexing, least obvious
```

Comment: I noticed that you do have to put a ```f``` between the last two curly brackets, otherwise the string will be printed with default formatting.

Comment: Nice catch, I added an explanation to the answer

Answer (score 8):

In addition to [@Talon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61709890/7802476), for those interested in f-strings, this also works.

```py
precision = 8
n = 7.12345678911

print(f'{n:.{precision}f}')
```